# How to empty an EntityFramework DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

How can I empty of an arbitrary `DbContext` without any knowledge about its inner objects and types? (wipe the database)

Unfortunately there is no generic way to do this. But this is useful i.e. when doing tests against local test-data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using reflection in a very sophisticated way. It looks strange but due to the fact that C# does not support a generic wildcard like `Java<?>` does we need a generic method and call it by reflection. Sure the solution performs slow, but its fast enough for local tests, debugging and development issues.

```
    public static void GenericRemoveSet<T>(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> set) where T:class
    {
        foreach (var item in set) set.Remove(item);
    }

    public static void ClearGenericDbContext(DbContext context)
    {
        var removeMethod = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetMethod("GenericRemoveSet");
        foreach (var prop in context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<>)))
        {
            var typedRemove = removeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First());
            typedRemove.Invoke(null, new object[]{prop.GetValue(context)});
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, there is something similar. Instead of checking the name, use `p.PropertyType.IsGenericType() && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)`

Comment: Hi guys, I get following error:

PropertyInfo[] no contiene una definición para 'Where' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión 'Where' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

It seems PropertyInfo[] doesn't recognize Where option, any ideas why that might be happening?